# bash run multiple files exit condition

Tags: bash, pip

I have a function like so

```
function generic_build_a_module(){

        move_to_the_right_directory
        echo 'copying the common packages'; ./build/build_sdist.sh;
        echo 'installing the api common package'; ./build/cache_deps.sh;
}
```

I want to exit the function if `./build/build_sdist.sh` doesn't finishes successfully.

here is the content `./build/build_sdist.sh`

```
... multiple operations....
echo "installing all pip dependencies from $REQUIREMENTS_FILE_PATH and placing their tar.gz into $PACKAGES_DIR"
pip install --no-use-wheel -d $PACKAGES_DIR -f $PACKAGES_DIR -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE_PATH $PACKAGES_DIR/*
```

In other words, how does the main function `generic_build_a_module` "knows" if the `./build/build_sdist.sh` finished successfully?

Comment: Try running `man bash` and search for the text `exit status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the exit status of a command by surrounding it with an `if`. `!` inverts the exit status. Use `return 1` to exit your function with exit status 1.

```
generic_build_a_module() {
    move_to_the_right_directory
    echo 'copying the common packages'
    if ! ./build/build_sdist.sh; then
        echo "Aborted due to error while executing build."
        return 1
    fi
    echo 'installing the api common package'
    ./build/cache_deps.sh;
}
```

If you don't want to print an error message, the same program can be written shorter using `||`.

```
generic_build_a_module() {
    move_to_the_right_directory
    echo 'copying the common packages'
    ./build/build_sdist.sh || return 1
    echo 'installing the api common package'
    ./build/cache_deps.sh;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `set -e`. This will exit your script immediately when some command exits with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:-

> 1. Run both the script in background and store their respective process id in two variables
> 2. Keep checking whether the scripts completed or not after an interval say for every 1 to 2 seconds.
> 3. Kill the process which is not completed after a specific time say 30 seconds

Example:

```
  sdist=$(ps -fu $USER|grep -v "grep"|grep "build_sdist.sh"| awk '{print $2}')
```

OR

```
 sdist=$(ps -fu $USER|grep [b]uild_sdist.sh| awk '{print $2}')

 deps=$(ps -fu $USER|grep -v "grep"|grep "cache_deps.sh"| awk '{print $2}')
```

Now use a `while` loop to check the status every after a certain interval or just check the status directly after 30 seconds like below

```
  sleep 30 

  if grep "$sdist"; then
     kill -8 $sdist
  fi
  if grep "$deps"; then
     kill -8 $deps
  fi
```

Comment: @Abhijt that doesn't answer my question. I don't need to know wheter the whole function executed successfully. I need to exit in the middle in case it doesn't

Comment: Aah now understood. Please see my modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit code status of the last executed command by checking the `$?` variable.  Exit code 0 is a typical indication that the command completed successfully.

Exit codes can be set by using `exit` followed by the code number within a script.

Here's [a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308207/exit-code-at-the-end-of-a-bash-script) regarding the use of `$?` with more detail, but to simply check this value try:

`echo "test";echo $?`

```
# Example
echo 'copying the common packages'; ./build/build_sdist.sh;
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "The last command exited with a non-zero code"
fi
```

`[ $? -ne 0 ]` Checks if the last executed commands error code is not equal to 0.  This is also useful to ensure that any negative error codes generated such as -1 are captured.

The caveat of the above approach is that we have only checked against the **last command executed** and not the `... multiple operations....` that you mentioned, so we may have missed an error generated by a command executed before `pip install`.

Depending on the situation you could `set -e` within a subsequent script, which instructs the shell to exit the script at the first instance a command exits with a non-zero status.

Another option would be to perform a similar operation as the example within `./build/build_sdist.sh` to check the exit code of each command.  This would give you the most control as to when and how the script finishes and allows the script to set it's own `exit` code.